# Return values from preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating a function that returns UA codes (from Google Analytics) from the page source of a website.

I've created a regex: '/[U][A]-\d{5,10}-\d{0,2}]/' for the UA codes.

I'm using preg_match_all but I don't seem to get anything back, while I know for sure that the website I'm using has at least one UA code.

This is what I've written so far:

```
<?php

$url = 'www.ibood.com/nl/nl/';

$options = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3
];

$init = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($init, $options);
$site = curl_exec($init);

preg_match_all('/[U][A]-\d{5,10}-\d{0,2}]/', $site, $matches);

print $matches[0][0];
```

I'm just getting a white screen.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: One thing to check when using something like curl to get a web page - save the page to a file and check the contents to see if it is what you expect.  A lot of times pages load data using javascript and so some content isn't loaded when you first get the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this RegEx `/[U][A]-\d{5,10}-\d{0,2}/`
You have an extra hook in your regex :)
Before: https://regex101.com/r/DDdJhA/1
After: https://regex101.com/r/UPA2iZ/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
/[U][A]-([0-9]{5,10})-([0-9]{0,2})+/
```

Always try to get a sample snippets of the response that you want to parse and use tools like https://regexr.com/

[image]